# Is it possible to decompose $K_{12,12}$ into four edge-disjoint copies of $3(K_{4,4}-I)$?

Tags: graph-theory

**Question**: Is it possible to decompose $K_{12,12}$ into four edge-disjoint copies of $3(K_{4,4}-I)$, where $I$ denotes a $1$-factor?

Here's a drawing of $3(K_{4,4}-I)$:

[image: drawing of the graph]

The same motivation for my question [Are there $3$ disjoint copies of $2K_{3,3} \cup (K_{5,5} \setminus C_{10})$ in $K_{11,11}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096176/are-there-3-disjoint-copies-of-2k-3-3-cup-k-5-5-setminus-c-10-in) but just another special case.

- The number of edges in $3(K_{4,4}-I)$ is $36$ and the number of edges in $K_{12,12}$ is $144 = 4 \times 36$.
- The graph $3(K_{4,4}-I)$ is $3$-regular, and $K_{12,12}$ is $(4 \times 3)$-regular.

I previously asked [Does $K_{12,12}$ decompose into $K_{4,4}-I$ subgraphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861777/does-k-12-12-decompose-into-k-4-4-i-subgraphs) which shows that $K_{12,12}$ decomposes into $12$ edge-disjoint copies of $K_{4,4}-I$, which is a necessary condition for the decomposition in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one such decomposition, found by simulated annealing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Here are the details of the graphs used:

- The second graph matches vertices $4,9,10,11$ to $8,5,6,4$, vertices $3,5,6,7$ to $12,3,10,9$, and vertices $1,2,8,12$ to $2,1,7,11$.
- The third graph matches vertices $5,7,8,9$ to $9,3,1,4$, vertices $1,2,3,12$ to $12,8,5,6$, and vertices $4,6,10,11$ to $2,7,11,10$.
- The fourth graph matches vertices $1,2,4,8$ to $8,12,10,9$, vertices $3,5,6,9$ to $2,7,5,11$, and vertices $6,10,11,12$ to $3,4,6,1$.

---

The actual answer may not be as interesting nearly two years later, but here is my Mathematica code for the simulated annealing, which can be more broadly useful.

(Here, each $3K_{4,4}-I$ is represented by a pair of permutations, one of the top and one of the bottom vertices. Each step we take is randomly switching two of the numbers in one of the 8 permutations we have. The energy value of a state is the number of edges of $K_{12,12}$ not covered, which we eventually bring down to $0$.)

```
edges[{perm1_, perm2_}] :=
  Join[
    Tuples[{perm1[[1 ;; 4]], perm2[[1 ;; 4]]}],
    Tuples[{perm1[[5 ;; 8]], perm2[[5 ;; 8]]}],
    Tuples[{perm1[[9 ;; 12]], perm2[[9 ;; 12]]}]]~Complement~
   Table[{perm1[[i]], perm2[[i]]}, {i, 1, 12}];

value[state_] := 12^2 - Length[Union @@ (edges /@ state)];
randomPerm[] := {RandomSample[Range[12]], RandomSample[Range[12]]}
randomSwitch[state_] := 
 Module[{h = RandomInteger[{1, 4}], i = RandomInteger[{1, 2}], j, k, 
   copy = state},
  {j, k} = RandomSample[Range[12], 2];
  copy[[h, i, {j, k}]] = Reverse[copy[[h, i, {j, k}]]];
  Return[copy];
  ]

currentState = 
  bestState = {randomPerm[], randomPerm[], randomPerm[], randomPerm[]};
currentEnergy = bestEnergy = value[currentState];
temp = 1;
While[Exp[-1/temp] > 1/1000,
 Do[
  nextState = randomSwitch[currentState];
  nextEnergy = value[nextState];
  If[nextEnergy < bestEnergy, bestState = nextState; 
   bestEnergy = nextEnergy];
  prob = Exp[-((nextEnergy - currentEnergy)/temp)];
  If[RandomReal[] < prob, currentState = nextState; 
   currentEnergy = nextEnergy];
  , {2000}];
 If[bestEnergy == 0, Break[]];
 temp *= 0.99; Print[{temp, currentEnergy}]
 ]
Print["Done ", bestEnergy];
```